# Как можно заменить цикл for на while?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(1,1000):
    if not i%100:
        print(str(i//100)*3)
```

Нужно было найти в промежутке от 1 до 1000 все трехзначные числа, цифры которых одинаковы;

Comment: А чем вас for не устраивает?

Comment: С таким методом получения трехзначных чисел `print(str(i//100)*3)` можно было сделать `for i range(1, 10)`, без if вообще и просто делать `print(str(i)*3)`

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
i = 1
while i<1000:
    if not i%100:
        print(str(i//100)*3)
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
digit = 1
while digit < 10:
    print(111 * digit)
    digit += 1
```

```
111
222
333
444
555
666
777
888
999
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем вам `while`? `for` проще и быстрее:

```
n = 3
limit = 10 ** n                            # 1000
repunit = (limit - 1) // 9                 #  111
for i in range(repunit, limit, repunit):   #  111, 222, 333, ..., 999
    print(i)
```